# Get the items causing most problems with Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to write a Powershell script that lists all the source files that were changed on a TFS due to a bug. The idea is that those files that get changed the most are candicates for a refactoring or a rewrite.

I found a [script](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/tag/get-tfsitemhistory/) to list the changed items since a date.

```
###############################################################
#                                                             
# Search for all unique file changes in TFS 
# for a given date/time range and collection location. 
# Write results to a manifest file.                                              
#                                                             
# Author:  Gary A. Stafford
# Created: 2012-04-18
# Revised: 2012-08-11                          
#                                                             
###############################################################

# Clear Output Pane
clear

# Enforce coding rules
Set-StrictMode -version 2.0

# Loads Windows PowerShell snap-in if not already loaded
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
}

# Variables - CHECK EACH TIME
[string] $tfsCollectionPath = "http://tfs2010/tfsCollection"
[string] $locationToSearch = "$/Development/AdventureWorks/"
[string] $outputFile = "c:\ChangesToTFS.txt"
[string] $dateRange = "D2012-07-08 00:00:00Z~"
[bool]   $openOutputFile = $true # Accepts $false or $true

# For a date/time range: 'D2012-08-06 00:00:00Z~D2012-08-09 23:59:59Z'
# For everything including and after a date/time: 'D2012-07-21 00:00:00Z~'

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver $tfsCollectionPath

# Add informational header to file manifest
[string] $outputHeader =
    "TFS Collection: " + $tfsCollectionPath + "`r`n" + 
    "Source Location: " + $locationToSearch + "`r`n" + 
    "Date Range: " + $dateRange + "`r`n" +
    "Created: " + (Get-Date).ToString() + "`r`n" +
    "======================================================================"

$outputHeader | Out-File $outputFile

Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch -Server $tfs -Version $dateRange `
-Recurse -IncludeItems | 

Select-Object -Expand "Changes" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Delete*'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -notlike '*Rename*'} | 

Select-Object -Expand "Item" | 
    Where-Object { $_.ContentLength -gt 0} | 

    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike '*/sql/*' } | 
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike '*/documentation/*' } | 
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike '*/buildtargets/*' } | 

    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike 'build.xml'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike '*.proj'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ServerItem -notlike '*.publish.xml'} | 

Select -Unique ServerItem | Sort ServerItem | 
Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | 
Out-File $outputFile -append

Write-Host `n`r**** Script complete and file written ****

If ($openOutputFile) { Invoke-Item $outputFile }
```

If I modify this script a little bit, I get all the Bugs:

```
$bugs = Get-TfsItemHistory $locationToSearch -Server $tfs -Version $dateRange `
-Recurse -IncludeItems | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AssociatedWorkItems | Where-Object {$_.WorkItemType -eq 'Bug'}
```

The problem I have is to combine the two. With the above script the context is switched to the Work-Item. How can I still list the Source files that match the criteria of having been changed because of a bug?

Answer (score 0):

According to you info, you can list all files changed as part of a Workitem. A example code as below:

```
function Get-TfsItem([int] $workItemNumber)
{
    Get-TfsServer njtfs -all |
        foreach { $_.wit.GetWorkItem($workItemNumber) } |
        foreach { $_.Links } |
        foreach { ([regex]'vstfs:///VersionControl/Changeset/(\d+)').matches($_.LinkedArtifactUri) } |
        foreach { $_.groups[1].value } |
        Get-TfsChangeset | 
        Select-TfsItem |
        Sort Path -Unique 
}
```

Comment: That approach sounds promising. However I get an error message when I try to execute `Get-TfsServer serverName -all`. The error is `get-tfsserver : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
At C:\Scripts\Get-Bugtroubled.ps1:24 char:5`

Comment: According to your error info : this is  a Cmdlets throwing error.  You need to match the version of the TFS Power Tools with your Visual Studio client. .....